# Inserting template text in a Google doc in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to create a simple script that prefills a template into a Google doc at the cursor point. I'm a bit stuck on how to add text and list items at the same time. Here is what I have:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();
  // Or FormApp or SpreadsheetApp.
  ui.createMenu('Templates')
      .addItem('Insert Template', 'insertTemplate')
      .addToUi();

}

function insertTemplate() {
  var cursor = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor();
  if (cursor) {

    var element = cursor.insertText("Some Header\n")
    element.setBold(true);

    var options = {weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'};
    var today  = new Date();
    dateStr = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options) + '\n\n';

    var element = cursor.insertText(dateStr);
    element.setBold(true);

    var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

    colors = ["blue", "red", "yellow"]
    colors.forEach( function(color) { 
      body.appendListItem(color + ": ").setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    });

  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }
}
```

It correctly outputs something like:

```
Feb 12, 2019

Some Header

 * blue
 * red
 * yellow
```

Now I want to append yet another simple line of text after the list but if I do it with cursor, it appends it before the date. How can I find the last position of the last item and insert text after it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to put texts and a list to the cursor position.
- You want to put a text to the last line as follows.

Result you want

```
Feb 12, 2019

Some Header

 * blue
 * red
 * yellow

sample text <--- here
```

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? In this modification, I used the following flow.

1. Retrieve the child index at the cursor.

   - In this modification, this child index is used as the offset of the body.
2. Put `dateStr`, `"Some Header\n"` and a list to the next child index.
3. Put a text to the last line.

I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Modified script:

```
function insertTemplate() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); // Added
  var cursor = doc.getCursor(); // Modified
  if (cursor) {
    var options = {weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'};
    var today  = new Date();
    dateStr = today.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options) + '\n\n';
    var body = doc.getBody();

    // Below script was modified.
    var offset = body.getChildIndex(cursor.getElement());
    body.insertParagraph(offset, dateStr);
    body.insertParagraph(++offset, "Some Header\n");
    colors = ["blue", "red", "yellow"]
    colors.forEach(function(color, i) {
      body.insertListItem(++offset, color + ": ").setGlyphType(DocumentApp.GlyphType.BULLET);
    });
    body.insertParagraph(--offset + colors.length, "sample text"); // Please set the text here.

  } else {
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert('Cannot find a cursor in the document.');
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- About `dateStr`, this was used from your script.

#### References:

- [getChildIndex(child)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getchildindexchild)
- [insertParagraph(childIndex, text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertparagraphchildindex-text)
- [insertListItem(childIndex, text)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#insertlistitemchildindex-text)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Perfect, I came to a similar result once I finally figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: @mart1n I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.